# How to use useAuthContext in root file for RN app

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm working on this side project using react-native with supabase for the database. I created this auth provider that I'd like to use in the root file (app.tsx) but the state continues to be null. The reason for why I'm attempting this method is because I need to conditionally render either `<Tab.Navigator />` or `<Stack.Navigator />` conditionally based on if the user is logged in or not.

Currently, the only way to get this to work is to do the supabase session fetching in app.tsx rather than using the session that is coming from `useAuthContext`. I can only access the data I need within the children components but not at the top level.

```js
// app.tsx
export default function App() {
  const [session, setSession] = useState(null);
  const { state: { session } } = useAuthContext(); // ideally I would like to do this

  // ideally i would NOT like to keep this
  useEffect(() => {
    supabase.auth.getSession().then(({ data: { session } }) => {
      setSession(session);
    });

    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
      setSession(session);
    });
  }, []);


  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <GluestackUIProvider config={config}>
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <NavigationContainer>
            {session && session.user ? (
              <TabNavigator key={session.user.id} session={session} />
            ) : (
              <StackNavigator />
            )}
          </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </GluestackUIProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

Is it possible to do this? If not, I'd love some tips on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The value of a `context` is only accessible by the components wrapped inside the respective `ContextProvider`. So, just move the logic to access and use the context value to a different component, wrap it inside the `AuthProvider` and you're good to go.

```
// AppNav.tsx
export default function AppNav() {
  const { state: { session } } = useAuthContext();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {session && session.user ? (
        <TabNavigator key={session.user.id} session={session} />
      ) : (
        <StackNavigator />
      )}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

// App.tsx
export default function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <GluestackUIProvider config={config}>
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <AppNav />
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </GluestackUIProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

Also, if you are trying to use multiple providers, just ensure they are called in the correct order.

```
// Provider A depends on Provider B
return (
  <ProviderB>
    <ProviderA>
      <Component/>
    <ProviderA/>
  <ProviderB/>
)
```